# chrome://downloads/ does not available in Google Chrome for Android

Tags: internal-storage, chrome-for-android

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab s2 and Google Chrome for Android is compatible with my Tab, so I installed it.

I clicked on a link to download a video file. Google chrome showed a toast message that the download has been started.

However, after this toast, I can't find where chrome downloaded the file.

I query `chrome://downloads` , but the browser displays `"This web page is not available "`

Comment: If you download a non-video file, are you able to download it? The video that you downloaded should be in that same folder.

Comment: If not, take a look at this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49774/how-to-download-via-chrome-on-nexus-7-with-jelly-bean-4-2-2

Comment: If you prefer having Downloads be available in the browser menu under 'Downloads'  you can still get that with Chromium. Install the latest build and navigate to chrome://flags. In the menu hit 'Find in Page', search 'downloads' and locate 'Enable downloads manager UI in the app menu'. Enable it and hit the blue button marked RELAUNCH NOW. Now downloads are back in the menu just like old times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a separate **Downloads** app, which shows a list of downloads from all apps. Downloads are saved in the "Downloads" directory in the SD card, which means that downloaded videos show up in the "Downloads" album in **Gallery**.

Answer (score -2):

On Android 4.4, you can access the download history in the App titled “My files.”

Comment: It's not universal.